# How can I set a count down timer in perl for doing a function repeatedly?

Tags: perl, file-transfer

I am copying a file from one file to another. I want to check whether the source file is available or not repeatedly in every 10 secs. How can I check it in between copying?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't fully understand the question. Does the following work?

```
use File::Copy;

sleep 10 until -e $source;
copy($source, $target);
```

Comment: I have one large file in my server, I want to copy it to the local. If the network get disconnected copying is failing. So I implemented the code for avoiding that and waiting for 1 mint for network. But it is not checking in between copying. It is checking only once. So If I got a count down timer, I can check the source repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`-e`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) file test and `sleep`:

```
perl -e'$s = "/source/path"; sleep 10 until -e $s; `rsync $s /destination/path`'
```

if you are in a perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;

# be careful if your paths contain spaces
my ($source, $dest) = qw(path/to/source path/to/dest);

sleep 10 until(-e $s);
system('rsync', $source, $dest);
```

Comment: I have one large file in my server, I want to copy it to the local. If the network get disconnected copying is failing. So I implemented the code for avoiding that and waiting for 1 mint for network. But it is not checking in between copying. It is checking only once. So If I got a count down timer, I can check the source repeatedly.